Derivation of Schrödinger equation in Feynman-Hibbs
I am going through the derivation in chapter 4-1 of "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals. Emended Edition" by Feynman and Hibbs. The chapter starts with a proof of the equivalence of the propagator formalism to Schrödinger equation formulation of quantum mechanics.
Let us consider a wavefunction at a time $t+\varepsilon$:
\begin{align}
    \psi(x,t+\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{A}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{K}(x_f,t+\varepsilon;x_i,t) \psi(x,t) dx,
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon$ is an infinitesimally small time interval and $\frac{1}{A}$ is the normalisation factor. We approximate the propagator:
\begin{align}
    \psi(x,t+\varepsilon) =&\frac{1}{A} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \varepsilon L\left(\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}, \frac{x+y}{2} \right)\right]\cr 
&\qquad \;\psi(y,t) dy .\tag{4.3}
\end{align}
Now let us apply the above to the case of a particle moving in one dimension in a potential $V(x,t)$:
\begin{align}
    \psi(x, t+\varepsilon) =& \frac{1}{A} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{m}{2} \left(\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}\right)^2 \varepsilon\right]\cr 
& \exp\left[- \frac{i}{\hbar} \varepsilon V\left(\frac{x+y}{2},t\right)\right] \psi\!\left(y,t\right) dy .\tag{4.4}
\end{align}
The first exponential contains the factor of $\frac{x-y}{\varepsilon}$ which will cause the propagator to oscillate rapidly when $y$ differs from $x$ considerably. Let us then make a substitution $y = x + \eta$.
\begin{align}
    \psi(x,t+\varepsilon) =& \frac{1}{A} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{m}{2} \left(\frac{\eta}{\varepsilon}\right)^2 \varepsilon\right] \cr 
&\exp\left[- \frac{i}{\hbar} \varepsilon V\left(x+ \frac{\eta}{2},t\right)\right] \psi\!\left(x+\eta,t\right) d\eta.\tag{4.5}
\end{align}
We expect that the most significant contribution will be yielded by small $\eta$ only.
We now expand $\psi$ in a Taylor series, keeping terms to first order in $\varepsilon$ and to second order in $\eta$:
\begin{align}
\psi (x,t) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} =& \frac{1}{A} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{m}{2} \frac{\eta^2}{\varepsilon}\right] \left[1 - \frac{i}{\hbar} \varepsilon V(x,t)\right]\cr 
& \left[\psi(x,t) + \eta \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\eta^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}\right] d\eta.\tag{4.6}
\end{align}
After solving the Gaussian integrals in $(4.6)$ and comparing terms linear in $\epsilon$ on both sides we arrive at the Schrödinger equation.
I understand the whole proof but am quite perplexed by the statement:

"We need only keep terms of order $\varepsilon$. This implies keeping second-order terms in $\eta$."

I cannot figure out how it is implied other than wishful thinking that we need a first-order derivative wrt $t$ and a second-order derivative wrt $x$.
Why is the wavefunction expanded keeping the terms to the first order in $\varepsilon$ while to the second order in $\eta$?

Anyone without the book is completely lost and it is not clear what you are asking. Note that questions (and answers) must be self-contained and useful for other users, a broader audience, too. You should a) give a more detailed reference (book title, authors, edition, chapter, page, equations numbers) and b) provide context, and type the relevant passage (using MathJax, not screenshots).

Briefly speaking, it follows from dimensional analysis that higher-order terms ${\cal O}(\eta^{n\geq 3})$ will [after the Gaussian $\eta$-integration (4.5)] only produce higher-orders terms ${\cal O}(\epsilon^{n/2})$, which are not important as $\epsilon\to 0$.
